# How to create a music player for iPhone/iPad which can buffer and play songs from server?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avplayer, buffering

I want to develop a music player for `iPhone/iPad` with the functionality:

-`Buffer` and `Play MP3` songs from server(no downloading).
-Play.
-Pause.
-Stop.
-Adjust Volume(Slider).
-Song Status/ Playing time for Song(slider).
-Repeat Song.
-Shuffle Songs.
-In the center of the Music Player there must be eq like dancing bars with song etc.

I am using AVPlayer for this but it is giving me trouble with Adjust Volume,Stop,Song Timers etc. With AVPlayer only `play/pause` and buffering is working.
Even i have used `AVAudioPlayer` also and it was working fine with all the functionality i needed but with local files only, may be i don't know any method play songs from server in `AVAudioPlayer`.

Help me with any suggestions,examples,sample code or tutorial.

Comment: I've done functions you mentioned above as a class, and open source it. Now you can find it on  
[GitHub](https://github.com/StreetVoice/HysteriaPlayer). Whatever you wanna use the class or treat it as an example. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing an MP3 stream seems like it should be a straightforward task that the Cocoa APIs would handle easily.

see this post [Live streaming](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html)

Comment: I have already went through this post, buffering song is not a problem it done but adjusting volume and other functionality are not compatible with buffered songs i think @navinsillu